# Selecting items from only one list of any three

Tags: html, wtforms

I have a webpage, where I want the user to select items only from any one list from three.

```
 A    B    C
-A1  -B1  -C1
-A2  -B2  -C2
-A3  -B3  -C3
```

Now the user must select only items (multiple) from either A, B or C and not more than one list. E.g.: A1,A2, A3 can be chosen from A but when B is selected selection of items under A must be deselected.
I would like to know whether such a form exists in HTML or in WTForms

Comment: The description of what you wish to accomplish is completely unintelligible. Try to reformulate, give some code example of what you tried and eventually some sketch of what your output should look like...

Comment: @MarinNedea Thank you for the suggestion. I have created an example. Please do have a look

Comment: This is not possible with HTML alone, but it is possible with javascript ( try jQuery  ?). What you wish is called "chained selection". There are a few tutorials on the web on how to achieve that. I don't know about WTForms .. maybe someone else could give you a hint on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be pure HTML, you'll have to take two steps. 
I think you might be talking about three Comboboxes. They are generated with the select command.

```
<select name="A">
    <option value="A1">A1</option>
    <option value="A2">A2</option>
</select>
```

To make only one of the three comboboxes active you could use a radio button set above:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="list" value="A" checked> A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="list" value="B"> B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="list" value="C"> C
</form>
```

then change the visibility of the Comboboxes based on the radio button picked.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you possibly know how this can be done in WTForms?